# how to ignore a certain value in a cell and move on to next row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table with four rows.

```
column1 | column2 | column3
---------------------------
 a      | role    | N/A
 b      | N/A     | N/A
 c      | N/A     | year
 c      | year    | N/A
```

is there a way that in a select statement I can get the results like

```
column1 | column2 | column3
---------------------------
 a      | role    | can be N/A or null
 c      | year    | year
```

ignoring the `N/A`. 
Thanks.

Comment: `where column2 is not null`?

Comment: @Taz . . . What happened to the second row?

Comment: @Gardon...ignore the second row as it's `N/A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's query needs additional filter:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        column1, 
        max(nullif(column2, 'N/A')) as column2,
        max(nullif(column3, 'N/A')) as column3
    from a_table
    group by 1
    ) s
where column2 notnull or column3 notnull
order by 1;

 column1 | column2 | column3
---------+---------+---------
 a       | role    |
 c       | year    | year
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Hi @Klin...I tried your query but still I am not getting the right results: in sub query itself I am getting `N/A, N/A` instead of `Year, Year`. Thanks.

Comment: The query is ok. Check if you really have `'N/A'` in your table (maybe there some spaces `' N/A '` or something like this).

Comment: apologies @Klin. Many thanks for you solution, It's working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select column1, max(nullif(column2, 'N/A')) as column2,
       max(nullif(column3, 'N/A')) as column3
from t
group by column1;
```

I realize that this is assuming that the the `column1` value in the second row is really "a" and not "b".

Comment: @Gordon...I tried your query but I am getting the `N/A` as results: in second row I am getting `N/A`, `N/A` instead of `Year`, `Year`